# Bash Package Automation /w OS Detect

Tags: bash

I have a fairly robust and accurate OS detect function written in bash that returns distribution and derivative (I think others may find it useful). I am now playing with ideas on how best to handle those outputs allowing the script to automatically choose and install a package list with the appropriate package manager for the distribution.
My first thought was to write a temporary file and check the outputs from there but that seems like a ugly way to handle it. Next I thought about returning exit codes that are not special meaning codes and a little if / elif  logic and I would be off to the races, also feels like a hacky way to make this work. Final thought would be to print to screen and store as a variable to once again use a bit of if logic. 

I have scrolled around on stack looking at similar questions and also flipped through Shell Scripting With Bash handbook hoping to get some inspiration writing a clean solution. But alas no spark. 

Any insights would be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
detect_os()
  {
MATCH=`uname -s`

if [ "${MATCH}" = "Linux" ]; then
  linux_distro
elif
   [ "${MATCH}" = "Darwin" ]; then
     printf "DISTRIBUTION=macosx \n"
     printf "VERSION=`uname -r` \n"
fi
  }

redhat_derivative()
  {
  local FILE=/etc/redhat-release

  grep -i 'red.*hat.*enterprise.*linux' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=rhel \n"; return; }
  grep -i 'red.*hat.*linux' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=rh \n"; return; }
  grep -i 'centos' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=centos \n"; return; }
  grep -i 'fedora' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=fedora \n"; return; }

  printf "DERIVATIVE=unknown \n"
 }

debian_derivative()
{
 if which lsb_release 2>&1 > /dev/null ; then
    printf "DERIVATIVE=`lsb_release --id --short 2> /dev/null` \n"
    return
else
    printf "DERIVATIVE=unknown \n"
    return
fi
  }

arch_derivative()
  {
local FILE=/etc/os-release
    grep -i 'arch' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=arch \n"; return; }
    grep -i 'manjaro' $FILE 2>&1 > /dev/null && { printf "DERIVATIVE=manjaro \n"; return; }

    printf "DERIVATIVE=unknown \n"
 }

linux_distro()
  {
 if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
  printf "DISTRIBUTION=redhat \n"
  redhat_derivative
elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
  printf "DISTRIBUTION=debian \n"
  debian_derivative
elif [ -f /etc/arch-release ]; then
  printf "DISTRIBUTION=arch \n"
  arch_derivative
fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two (similar) versions in my personal shell lib (one for bash and another for unfriendly POSIX shells (I'm looking at you dash.)) I check /etc/issue for Linux versions, (roughly) like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

########
## OS ##
########

os () {
    ISSUE="$(cat /etc/issue)"
    if [ "$(grep -iE 'centos|redhat|yellowdog' /etc/issue)" ]; then
        echo ${ISSUE%% *}
    elif [ "$(grep -iE 'debian|ubuntu' /etc/issue)" ]; then
        echo ${ISSUE%% *}
    fi

}

###############
## installer ##
###############

installer () {
    OS=$(os)
    if [ "$OS" ]; then
         if [ "$OS" = 'Debian' ] || [ "$OS" = 'Ubuntu' ]; then
            echo 'apt-get install -y'
            return 0
        elif [ "$OS" = 'Gentoo' ]; then
            echo 'emerge'
        elif [ "$OS" = 'CentOS' ] || [ "$OS" = 'Redhat' ]; then
            echo 'yum install -y'
        fi
    fi
}
#############
## install ##
#############
#
# generalises automation of install
# in an OS independent way.
# i.e. if Debian, CentOS, Gentoo, Slackware, FreeBDS, OpenSolaris
# this will find a way to install ALL of $@
#

install() {
     eval $(which sudo) $(installer) $1
     [ "$?" -gt 0 ] && echo "Failed to install $1" >&2 && return 0
     return 1
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to to utilize your technique with my code above to create the function that I need.

Comment: What does `cat /etc/issue|grep .` give you on the command line?